# Loopback - "Cannot read property 'connector' of null" in Connector hooks

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I tried to follow this example

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Connector+hooks

```
var connector = MyModel.getDataSource().connector;
  connector.observe('before execute', function(ctx, next) {
  // ...
   next();
});
```

But the property 'connector' seems to be undefined. I need to add a connector hook in the boot script. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this to add a connector.

> In server/datasource.json

```
{
  "db": {
    "host": "",
    "port": 0,
    "database": "",
    "password": "",
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "user": ""
  },
  "mongodb": {
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "drugcorner",
    "password": "12345",
    "name": "mongodb",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "user": "robins"
  }
}
```

We have have MongoDb datasource datasource defined with name `mongodb`.
Now to use a connector for `mongodb` inside any boot files.

> server/boot/testConnector.js

```
var mongoConnector = app.dataSources.mongodb.connector;
```

Comment: @mauro did u get the answer? Is it working for your purpose.

Comment: Yes it works, but i need to append a hook to existing connector declared statically in a JSON file.

Comment: @MauroLosciale I have edited the answer. Also, explain more abt what you want to achieve. If this is the answer you were looking then click the green tick mark. So that other may find it useful too.

Comment: @Reza use `const app = Model.app;` to access app inside model